# Representing $\frac{1}{x^2}$ in powers of $(x+2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I was asked to represent $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ in powers of $(x+2)$ using the fact that $\frac{1}{1 − x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...$. I am able to represent $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as a power series, but I am struggling withdoing it in powers of $(x+2)$. This is what I attempted.

$I.$ Firstly, I used the simple expansion

$$\ln(x+1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n}$$

which comes from the fact that $\frac{1}{1 − x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...$. I then noticed that

$$\ln(x) = \ln(1+(x-1))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{n}$$

$II$. $-f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is the second derivative of $\ln(x)$, so that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{(x-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{(x-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{(x-1)^{n-2}}{n^2(n-1)}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

from what plainly follows that $$\frac{1}{x^2} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{(x-1)^{n-2}}{n^2(n-1)}$$

$III.$ Of course, this expansion is not in powers of $(x+2$). What I pressumed would be the logical thing to do is to repeat these steps but, instead of the using $\ln(1 + (x-1))$, using the equivalent

$$\ln(-2 + (x+2))=\ln((-2)(1+\frac{x+2}{(-2)})) = \ln(-2)+\ln(1+\frac{x+2}{(-2)})$$

I expected to be able to use this because the second term is of the form $\ln(1+ u)$ where $u$ is some function of $x$, and we know the expansion of such expression. However, $\ln(-2)$ is nonsense, since $\ln(x)$ is defined only for $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Is there an alternative, better way to do this or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = x + 2$ so that $x = u - 2$. Then,
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{(u - 2)^2} 
= \frac{1}{(2 - u)^2}
= \frac{1}{4 \bigl(1 - \tfrac12 u \bigr)^2}
= \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{(1 - v)^2}
$$
where $v = \tfrac12 u$ or $u = 2v$.

We can derive a nice power series for $(1 - v)^{-2}$ centered at $v = 0$ by differentiating the geometric series in $v$. Try it yourself.

> $$ \frac{1}{(1 - v)^2} = \frac{d}{dv} \frac{1}{1 - v} = \frac{d}{dv} \sum_{m=0}^\infty v^m = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dv} v^m = \sum_{m=1}^\infty m\, v^{m-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+1)\, v^n,$$ where the sum is reindexed by $n = m - 1$ or $m = n+1$.

Now, back substitute $v \mapsto u \mapsto x$. Again, try to do this yourself before revealing the spoiler.

> $$ \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{(1 - v)^2} = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\, \bigl(\tfrac12(x + 2) \bigr )^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^{n+2}} \, (x+2)^n$$

Comment: Wow. First of all, this solution via double substitution is extremely elegant. I would have never found it myself. Secondly, the hintted format is much appreciated. An excellent answer. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad that this helps. The first substitution is motivated by the fact that you wanted to expand in $x + 2$, so it's easier to give that quantity a name. This seems magical at first, but is a technique that you can regularly use. The second substitution is a bit more subtle and it comes from recognizing that we know how to expand expressions of the form $(1 - v)^{-p}$ for $p = 1, 2, \dots$ by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series (the $p=1$ case).

Answer (score 2):

The standard riff here is to first notice that $1/x^2$ is ($-1$ times) the derivative of $1/x$... and that differentiation preserves power series with a given center. Then some algebra gives
$$ 1/x \;=\; 1/(x+2-2) \;=\; {-1\over 2}{1\over 1-{x+2\over 2}}
\;=\; {-1\over 2} \sum_{n\ge 0} ({x+2\over 2})^n
$$
Differentiating (and multiplying through by $-1$) gives
$${1\over x^2} \;=\; {1\over 2}\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\over 2}\left({x+2\over 2}\right)^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way.

$\frac 1  {x^{2}}=\frac 1  {((x+2)-2)^{2}}=\frac  1 4 \frac  1 {(1-\frac {x+2} 2)^{2} } =\frac 1  2\frac  d {dx} \frac  1{1-\frac {x+2} 2}=\frac 1 2\frac d {dx} [\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac {x+2} 2 )^{n}]$. Can you continue?

Comment: This isn't correct since 
$$
\frac{1}{(1 - u)^2} \neq \frac{1}{1 - u^2}
$$ 
and you want to represent the former but your series is in terms of the latter.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks. I have edited.